# QGIS Georeferencer and Coordinate Systems

Tags: qgis, raster, georeferencing, ubuntu

I'm having an issue with Ubuntu and Windows versions of QGIS where the georeferencer does not properly assign the coordinate system to the output raster.

When I assign the output CRS to 'EPSG:900913 - Google Mercator', the output is set to "EPSG:3395 - WGS 84 / World Mercator"

Its not until i 'set layer CRS' of the newly georeferenced raster to 'EPSG:900913 - Google Mercator' that the raster draws correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if you're doing anything wrong. It might be worth repeating the georeferencing, but assigning EPSG:3857 to the raster (in QGIS the definitions for EPSG:900913 and EPSG:3857 are identical, but 3857 is preferred). N.

Comment: I had several misplaced georeferenced rasters using 900913. After switching to 3857 the problem disappered. They should be identical, but qgis treats them not identical ;-) Apart from that, 900913 will be depricated in future versions of qgis, so better switch to 3857 now.

Comment: Also: the resultant GEOtiff went pretty cleanly into Tilemill - just required the custom SRS info:


+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs